# Difference between 2 times PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Hi I know you may think that many of them may have asked this question, but the scenario is quite different.

Since I am calculating the total shift hours done by labor monthly wise the hours will be more than 24hrs. I have achieved this by DateInterval.

Now I have 2 times and want to get the difference of those in php.

```
$workedHours        = '78:25:10';
$miscSpentHours     = '02:26:11';

$totalWorkedHours = $workedHours - $miscSpentHours; // Must Result - 75:59:59
```

I have used sub, diff, strtotime with it but not getting properly. I am converting it to appropriate date types while conversion.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use `DateTime` class

Comment: I am getting the following exception - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (78:25:10) at position 0 (7): Unexpected character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving DateTime Difference in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573313/resolving-datetime-difference-in-php)

Comment: @Touheed Khan its not duplicate. The link you sent is having date but mine is only time which has more than 24 hours.

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari  try this.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928021/getting-time-difference-between-two-times-in-php

Comment: @Touheed Kahn. Nope your 2nd link also didn't work for me. Just check the comments for that answer.

Comment: @Fabian Even your link links to the same question. The accepted answer doesn't answer my question type. Please check the comment too. It wont work properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can trans it to seconds then do the subtract, then trans the result back.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. but this should put you in the right direction

```
<?php

$hours = 70;//enter number of hours
$zero    = new DateTime('@0');
$offset  = new DateTime('@' . $hours * 3600);//convert to minutes
$diff    = $zero->diff($offset);


$formattedHours = $diff->format('%a Days, %h Hours, %i Minutes');//get format in days hours and minutes

$start_date = new DateTime($formattedHours);//pass in contruct
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('02:26:11'));//do difference
echo $since_start->days.' days total<br>';
echo $since_start->y.' years<br>';
echo $since_start->m.' months<br>';
echo $since_start->d.' days<br>';
echo $since_start->h.' hours<br>';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check my function[TimeToSec()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874702/67332) to convert HH:MM:SS to seconds
2. subtract
3. convert seconds back to HH:MM:SS (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870843/67332)).